# How can I change the font-size of the title?

Tags: javascript, css, json, qliksense

I am using the [SenseDateRangePicker](https://github.com/NOD507/SenseDateRangePicker) extension and I was asked to change the font-size of this output ("select date range"):

[image]

I changed the font of almost everything in the CSS file of this extension but I can't find the styling that corresponds to this output. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Can you add the rendered html code so that we can review and help you with the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/NOD507/SenseDateRangePicker.git

Comment: The github project url for the tool won't help me with the styling. Can you provide the rendered html content as I asked earlier?

Comment: Open your dev tools and see what CSS selectors match the element. Overwrite the font-size in those.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. @thebrownkid These are the only files I have. Sorry but I can't find the html content you asked.

Comment: @skyline3000 I will try it. Thanks again.

Comment: @thebrownkid thanks for your tip. I finally found it and already changed the font-size. It was very easy.